# Apparent error in R acf calculation

Tags: r

I have a series

```
D=c(1.7,5.4, 3.8, 9.7, -4.5, -1.1, 0.5)
```

I simply want to calculate the ACF at various lags for this function.
If I run acf(D) in R I get the following:
Autocorrelations of series ‘d’, by lag

```
     0      1      2      3      4      5      6 
 1.000 -0.055 -0.007 -0.339 -0.077 -0.029  0.007
```

I went to check this ACF by manually computing it.
A very simple way to do ACF is to do the correlation between D and Lag(D,lag_num)

So for example the ACF of D at lag 1 is the correlation between D and lag(D,1).
This is widely regarded as an acceptable formula. Yet if you do this

```
# for the first one
temp_a = c(1.7,5.4,3.8,9.7,-4.5,-1.1) 
temp_b = c(5.4,3.8,9.7,-4.5,-1.1,0.5) 
cor(temp_a,temp_b)
```

you get the following numbers:

```
-0.057  0.01575  -0.49937
```

For lags 1,2,3 respectively.

I am very confused in this discrepancy. Especially since the manual checked numbers make a lot more sense. I know R must be correct on such a simple function but I can't figure out why they are so different. And would appreciate any clarification!

Thanks!

Comment: You write "if you do this" where it would be much clearer to see code.

Comment: temp_a = c(1.7,5.4,3.8,9.7,-4.5,-1.1)
temp_b = c(5.4,3.8,9.7,-4.5,-1.1,0.5)
cor(temp_a,temp_b)
This is the example for the first lag auto correlation

Comment: `cor(temp_a, temp_b)` yields `-0.057` for me, which is pretty darn close to the ACF result...

Comment: There are multiple ways to calculate the autocorrelation of two series. There's the Pearson Autocorrelation, which is what using the correlations between a series and a lagged version of that series would come close to. Then there is the "Autocorrelation Function." The calculations are different and each has it's merits in different places. You can find an explanation of the two methods in Forecasting Principles and Applications by Stephen DeLurgio on pages 67-70.

Comment: Here is a free source that shows the Autocorrelation Function. https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/2

This shows an example using R and is the formula used in the `acf()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your formula is off.  This manual calculation matches `acf`

```
x <- D - mean(D)
sum(x[1:6] * x[2:7]) / sum(x^2)
[1] -0.05503743
```

See http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35c.htm for the formula I used.

Note that the sample mean of the *entire* time series is incorporated in this formula, which would be missing in your implementation.

Comment: Good to hear.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: This did, I was using the first formula from the wikipedia page and not this version where you demean the series first. Thanks!