# Calculating Autocorrelation Function from scratch in R

Tags: r, statistics

I want to understand how to calculate Autocorrelation Function from scratch in `R`. How can I use `cor(x=y, y=lag(x=y, k=2))` to get `ACF` when `y` is a `ts` object?

I've already tried all choices for `use` argument [`use = "complete.obs" # c("everything", "all.obs", "complete.obs", "na.or.complete", "pairwise.complete.obs")`].

```
set.seed(1)
y <-ts(data = rnorm(20), start = c(2010, 1), frequency = 4)
y

# Qtr1        Qtr2        Qtr3        Qtr4
# 2010  0.91897737  0.78213630  0.07456498 -1.98935170
# 2011  0.61982575 -0.05612874 -0.15579551 -1.47075238
# 2012 -0.47815006  0.41794156  1.35867955 -0.10278773
# 2013  0.38767161 -0.05380504 -1.37705956 -0.41499456
# 2014 -0.39428995 -0.05931340  1.10002537  0.76317575

acf(x=y, plot=FALSE)
# Autocorrelations of series ‘y’, by lag
# 
# 0.00   0.25   0.50   0.75   1.00   1.25   1.50   1.75   2.00   2.25   2.50   2.75   3.00   3.25 
# 1.000 -0.122 -0.185 -0.049  0.147 -0.283 -0.255  0.212  0.097 -0.120 -0.181  0.286 -0.063  0.094 

cor(
      x   = y
    , y   = lag(x=y, k=2)
    , use = "complete.obs" # c("everything", "all.obs", "complete.obs", "na.or.complete", "pairwise.complete.obs")
    )

# [1] 1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32570260/3573401

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have two problems.

**First problem**: `cor(x, lag(x, k = k))` will always be 1 because the two series are not temporally aligned.
You need to use `ts.union` or `cbind.ts` before using `cor`

```
X <- ts.union(yt = y, yt2 = lag(x = y, k =  2))
head(X)
##            yt      yt2
## [1,]       NA -0.62645
## [2,]       NA  0.18364
## [3,] -0.62645 -0.83563
## [4,]  0.18364  1.59528
## [5,] -0.83563  0.32951
## [6,]  1.59528 -0.82047
tail(X)
##              yt      yt2
## [17,]  1.124931 -0.01619
## [18,] -0.044934  0.94384
## [19,] -0.016190  0.82122
## [20,]  0.943836  0.59390
## [21,]  0.821221       NA
## [22,]  0.593901       NA
```

The problem is that without time index, the raw data are the same (with a temporal shift). You can test yourself

```
x1 <- as.vector(y)
x2 <- as.vector(lag(y, k = 2))
all.equal(x1, x2)
## [1] TRUE
```

Therefore, if you to compute the correlation coefficient between a a time series and its lag, you can use `X` (created using `ts.union`)

```
cor(X[, 1], X[, 2], use = "complete.obs")
## [1] -0.19018
```

Still the results is different from `acf(y, plot = FALSE)$acf[3]`

```
acf(y, plot = FALSE)$acf[3]
## [1] -0.18521
```

Which bring us to the **second reason** why you can't use `cor` to compute `acf`:

The mathematical definition of the Acf suppose a least a second-order stationarity (mean and variance equal for each lag):

[image]

But if you use the standard implementation of `cor`, for each series, a different value for mean and variance will be computed (the value for the lag will be different from the original series).

```
c0 <- var(y)
m <- mean(y)
n <- length(y)
ct <- sum((X[, 1] - m) * (X[, 2] - m), na.rm = TRUE) / (n - 1)
(rt <- ct / c0)
## [1] -0.18521

all.equal(rt, acf(y, plot = FALSE)$acf[3])
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks @dickoa for useful answer. Would appreciate if you also guide how to calculate PACF. I found [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18599/3903) but I'm not getting correct answers. Any thoughts.

Comment: @MYaseen208 Calculating the pacf is more difficult you need to estimate someAR coefficients usually using the Yule-Walker recursive method. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18599/pacf-manual-calculation

Answer (score 1):

Got the correct answer following the link provided by @khashaa. Thanks

```
acf(x=y, plot=FALSE)
# Autocorrelations of series ‘y’, by lag
# 
# 0.00   0.25   0.50   0.75   1.00   1.25   1.50   1.75   2.00   2.25   2.50   2.75   3.00   3.25 
# 1.000 -0.122 -0.185 -0.049  0.147 -0.283 -0.255  0.212  0.097 -0.120 -0.181  0.286 -0.063  0.094 

sum((y-mean(y))*(lag(x=y, k=0)-mean(y)))/sum((y-mean(y))^2)
[1] 1
sum((y-mean(y))*(lag(x=y, k=1)-mean(y)))/sum((y-mean(y))^2)
[1] -0.1222859
sum((y-mean(y))*(lag(x=y, k=2)-mean(y)))/sum((y-mean(y))^2)
[1] -0.1852114
sum((y-mean(y))*(lag(x=y, k=3)-mean(y)))/sum((y-mean(y))^2)
[1] -0.04940401
```